# Problem with SfExtraFormPlugin (ReCaptcha)

Tags: php, symfony1

I use symfony 1.4.8 . I want to add ReCaptcha to my form , I use SfExtraFormPlugin, I use  [Readme](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/10/18/spice-up-your-forms-with-some-nice-widgets-and-validators)

So , According readme, I add

```
    $this->widgetSchema['captcha'] = new sfWidgetFormReCaptcha(array(
  'public_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_public_key')
));

$this->validatorSchema['captcha'] = new sfValidatorReCaptcha(array(
  'private_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_private_key')
));
```

My action.class

```
  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind(

     $request->getParameter($form->getName()),
     $request->getFiles($form->getName())             
                    );
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $voice_post = $form->save();

      $this->redirect('post/index', $post);
    }
  }
```

Than  I must add  to my action.class

```
$captcha = array(
  'recaptcha_challenge_field' => $request->getParameter('recaptcha_challenge_field'),
  'recaptcha_response_field'  => $request->getParameter('recaptcha_response_field'),
);
$this->form->bind(array_merge($request->getParameter('contact'), array('captcha' => $captcha)));
```

So, I do not know how to do it right.

when I do

```
  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {

     $captcha = array(
  'recaptcha_challenge_field' => $request->getParameter('recaptcha_challenge_field'),
  'recaptcha_response_field'  => $request->getParameter('recaptcha_response_field'),
);

    $form->bind(

            array_merge (

            $request->getParameter($form->getName()),
            $request->getFiles($form->getName()),
            array('captcha' => $captcha)

                    ));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $voice_post = $form->save();

      $this->redirect('post/index', $post);
    }
  }
```

I have an error

***This form is multipart, which means you need to supply a files array as the bind() method second argument.***

Captcha in _form.php

```
<?php echo $form['captcha']->renderRow() ?>
```

Source code of the page :

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="voice_post_captcha">Captcha</label></th>
  <td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean',
    lang : 'en'
    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LcS4MESAAAAADg7FPXAuPfIwvIeFS7LhSGEhUdb"></script>
    <noscript>
      <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LcS4MESAAAAADg7FPXAuPfIwvIeFS7LhSGEhUdb" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
      <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
    </noscript>
    </td>
</tr>
```

p.s Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$form->bind(
    array_merge (
        $request->getParameter($form->getName()),
        $request->getFiles($form->getName()),
        array('captcha' => $captcha)
    )
);
```

With:

```
$form->bind(
    array_merge (
        $request->getParameter($form->getName()),
        array('captcha' => $captcha)
    ),
    $request->getFiles($form->getName())
);
```

The second parameter of the bind function needs to be the files array. The array_merge call is merging the captcha results into the the form values array.